# R: Counting (or summing) cells that are =1 in two selected columns

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R. I have a huge binary data set and want to find the number of cells that are equal to 1 for, say, both columns 7 and column 6616 of my data set. How can I write the code?
I tried `colSums(data1.sub.added[,7]!=0 && data1.sub.added[,6616])!=0`but coLSums does not work on a one dimensional object and gives and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sum(data1.sub.added[,7] == 1 & data1.sub.added[,6616] == 1)
```